# Java hibernate with Apache Shiro login authentication returning false after "successfully" logging in

Tags: java, hibernate, angular, authentication, shiro

I'm using Java Hibernate with Apache Shiro for user login and authentication.  I use this code to authenticate the user and it works as intended (as far as I can tell).

```
 try {
        AuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(user.getUsername().toUpperCase(), user.getPassword());


        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        Session session = currentUser.getSession();
        session.setAttribute( "username", user.getUsername());
        System.out.println("USER: " + session.getAttribute("username"));

        currentUser.login(token);

        System.out.println( "User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() + "] logged in successfully." );
        System.out.println( "Is user authenticated? " + currentUser.isAuthenticated());
    }
    catch (ExcessiveAttemptsException eae ) { 
         eae.getStackTrace();
         eae.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }
```

This works if the correct credentials are provided or return forbidden exception if they're incorrect.

After I use another method to check if the user is authorised,  But it ALWAYS returns false (when it should be true).  I'm not sure what's causing this.

```
   try {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        return SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated();

    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }
```

The *currentUser* is null when checking in debug mode.

I can also use another approach but it returns a nullPointerException in the second line.

```
try {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();

        User user = userDAO.find(securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());

        if (user == null) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        UserModel result = new UserModel(user);

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

        return result;
}
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return null;
```

I use shiro.ini to connect to a local database.
[Update] I've added a debug login filter that can log in automatically when it's enabled (using a Servlet) and it works as intended.  
I've added a URL section and it works when I use authcBasic but not when I use authc in Shiro.  I can check by calling the method `isAuthenticated()` or `getCurrentUser()`.  Using authcBasic returns all the correct information but authc returns false/null.  I also cannot logout when using authcBasic unless I clean the web browser.  The method `SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();` sets the isAuthenticated boolean to false (when I debug) but doesn't seem to have any actual effect on the session.

```
# =======================
# Shiro INI configuration
# =======================

[main]
# Debug filter to automatically login
debugLogin = util.DebugLoginFilter
debugLogin.enabled = false
debugLogin.username = ADMIN
debugLogin.password = ADMIN

jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password from user where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role from user_role INNER JOIN user ON     user_role.id = user.user_role_id where user.username = ?

# Datasource for the jdbc realm
ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
ds.databaseName = database
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

authc.usernameParam = username
authc.passwordParam = password
authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

[roles]
admin = *

[urls]
/ = debugLogin, authcBasic
/index.html = debugLogin, authcBasic
/api/login = anon
/api/login/me = authcBasic
/api/login/logout = authcBasic
/api/** = debugLogin, authcBasic
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Apologies if I made any mistakes, I'm new here!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This message displays in the console when running the Apache server:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory - Realms have been explicitly set on the SecurityManager instance - auto-setting of realms will not occur.
```

Comment: Where in your application are you calling SecurityUtils.getSubject(); that is failing?  Same request or another request? Are you calling it from within a filter or spawned thread?

Comment: Hi @teacurran I'm calling it from the frontend (using Angular 2) as a POST request passing the username and password to the Java backend.  The SecurityUtils.getSubject(); works when its being used to log in (it shows all the correct details when I debug the code), but it doesn't work when I call it again from the the frontend to check if the user is actually logged in/authenticated.

Comment: right. so you are calling a GET request that is hitting your REST api service.  How is the REST service handled, with a filter? servlet?  If filter, it could be getting called before the shiro filter, this would cause it to not work.

Comment: @teacurran - I'm using a UserDAO which extends a UserFilter interface.  I use this when the user logs in to check if they exist (shown in the first code segment above) then create a UserModel and then commit the changes.  I'm not sure if this is the correct approach but it seems like the fault might be there as the user settings are not saved properly.

Comment: @teacurran - I've updated the question and added a console message when running the server.  I can't find anything online, not sure if it's relevant if I'm connecting to a local database.

Comment: is the userFilter a servlet filter? is so, make sure it is in the chain after ShiroFilter. Also, you're inserting the user after shiro auth? If the user doesn't exist how does shiro find it with jdbc?

Comment: Do you have a `[urls]` section in your shiro.ini: [example](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/samples/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/shiro.ini#L51-L59) ?

Also, you should update to the latest version of Shiro (this will not solve your problem though)

Comment: @BrianDemers - I've updated the shiro.ini file and explained the changes, and I will update Shiro to the latest version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.  The problem was not the code but rather the approach I used.

I'm using Angular 2 for the front-end and Java Hibernate for the back-end.  Shiro cannot communicate with the front-end because it's in a different directory.  But it works as it should after building the angular app and copying the dist content into the WebContent in the back-end.

I will use the debug login filter to manually login when I'm developing (then disable it in Shiro once it's ready for production).

I will keep the code snippets in case someone else has this problem.

Comment: When we do `currentUser.login()`, where actually is the system checking the `username` and `password` provided by client side with the one stored in database in the server side?